# Best way to insert a node into this linked list?

Tags: c, linked-list

So this is my code for the a linked list program.  I know it's not that great, but it works.  I want to change the ins() function so that new elements are inserted to the list by magnitude.. i.e., the last node on the list will contain the greatest integer, and the smallest the first.  The integers are read in from a text file, and as you can see in main(), the INSERT and REMOVE commands in the text file are interpreted as commands to either insert (the following integer on the next line) into the list, or remove an element from the list.  How can I do this with my existing code?  I tried modifying my ins() function, but was unable to get my list ordered properly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    int number;
    struct node *next;
};

/* prototypes */

void ins(struct node *llist, int number);
void rem(struct node *llist);
void sho(struct node *llist);

int main(void)
{
    int number;
    char command[6];
    struct node *llist;
    struct node *root;

    llist = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    llist->number = 0;
    llist->next = NULL;

    root = llist;

    printf("addr: \n\n%p,%p\n\n", &llist, &root);

    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("a3data.txt", "r");

    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("\n----------------------------------------\n");
        printf("| Error.  Did not read file.  Exiting. |\n");
        printf("----------------------------------------\n\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        while ((fscanf(file, "%s", command)) != EOF)
        {
            if((strcmp(command, "INSERT"))==0)
                {
                    fscanf(file, "%d", &number);
                    printf("\nINSERT            ", number);
                    ins(llist, number);
                    sho(llist);
                }
            else if((strcmp(command, "REMOVE"))==0)
                {
                    printf("\n         REMOVE   ");                
                    rem(llist);
                    sho(llist);
                }
        }
    }

    printf("\n");
    free(llist);
    return(0);
}

void ins(struct node *llist, int number) 
{
    while(llist->next != NULL)
    {
        llist = llist->next;
    }

    llist->next = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    llist->next->number = number;
    llist->next->next = NULL;
}

void rem(struct node *llist)
{
    while(llist->next->next != NULL)
    {
        llist = llist->next;
    }

    llist->next = NULL;
}

void sho(struct node *llist)
{
    while(llist->next != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d ", llist->number);
        llist = llist->next;
    }

    printf("%d", llist->number);
}
```

Comment: So you need to insert node in sorted order? hmm

Comment: Does it work properly, I have doubt I think in declarations `struct node *llist` should be `struct node** llist` otherwise it will not effect at calling

Comment: [`void sortedInsert(struct node** head_ref, struct node* new_node)`](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/given-a-linked-list-which-is-sorted-how-will-you-insert-in-sorted-way/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified function in your case

```
void ins(struct node *llist, int number) 
{
  struct node *llist1;
  while(llist->next != NULL)
  {
    if (llist->next->number > number)
       break;
    llist = llist->next;
  }

  llist1 = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  llist1->number = number;
  llist1->next = llist->next;
  llist->next = llist1;
}
```

Comment: Perfect!  I understand!  I would up-vote to give you points if I could, but I don't have enough rep.

Answer (score 0):

in `ins()` function, instead of

```
while(llist->next != NULL)
```

use

```
while((llist->next != NULL) && (llist->number < number))
```

This will help you to sort while inserting itself.

Also in `rem()` function, you have to free the memory that you dynamically allocate.

Answer (score 0):

Your insert is simply adding the element in the tail. You have to write code to compare the present value of node(list->number) against the number to be inserted. If the current value is greater than the number to be inserted, then the number has to be inserted before the current node. For this, you will have to keep previous pointer also. The code, I have written, is just to understand the logic, Didn't check for correctness.

```
if(llist->number > innumber) {
    node *newNode = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node);
    newNode->number = innumber; 
    prevPointer->next = newNode;
    newNode->next = llist;
}
```